# How to configure FOSRestBundle to not interfere with Custom Exception Controller

Tags: symfony, exception, fosrestbundle

I have just updated my Symfony 2.7 page to 2.8. Beside Symfony itself a number of other packages have been updated as well. `FOSRestBundle` has been updated from version 1.4 to 2.1.

After the update the `CustomExceptionController` I configured for `Twig` does not work any more. Error like 404 or 500 show the default exception page instead of my custom page.

This is the configuration:

```
// app/config/config.yml
...
twig:
    exception_controller:  app.exception_controller:showAction


// src/MyAppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
app.exception_controller:
    class: MyAppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController
    arguments: ['@twig', '%kernel.debug%', "@translator.default" ]


// src/MyAppBundle/Controller/CustomExceptionController.php
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;    

class CustomExceptionController extends ExceptionController {   

protected $translator;

public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, $debug, Translator $translator) {
    parent::__construct($twig, $debug);
    $this->translator = $translator;
}

public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null) {
    ...
}
```

With the help of [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853878) I was able to figure out, that the problem is caused by a config change I made in accordance with the `FOSRestBundle` [Update notes](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/2.0/UPGRADING-2.0.md):

```
removed the ability of the AccessDeniedListener to render a response.
Use the FOSRestBundle or the twig exception controller in complement.
...
After:
     fos_rest:
        access_denied_listener: true
        exception: true # Activates the FOSRestBundle exception controller
```

Following this hint and the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/4-exception-controller-support.html), I added `fos_rest:exception:enabled: true` to the `config.yml`:

```
// Before the Update:
fos_rest:
    ...
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true  
    exception:
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
        messages:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': true

// After the Update:
fos_rest:
    ...
    access_denied_listener:
        json: true  
    exception:
        enabled: true  # <<< Added this line
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
        messages:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': true
```

According to the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/4-exception-controller-support.html), the option `fos_rest:exception:enabled: true` was already necessary in version 1.4 to actually enable the FOS Exception Controller. Thus I am not sure, if the configuration was correct before the update and if the FOS Exception Controller worked as intended.

However, not it is necessary to set `fos_rest:exception:enabled: true` to correctly use the `access_denied_listener`.

**So the Problem is:**
`access_denied_listener` should be able to work properly (`fos_rest:exception:enabled: true` has to be set) and my `Twig` Exception Controller should still handle exceptions (does not work if `fos_rest:exception:enabled: true` is set).

**How do I properly set up / use the FOS Exception Controller without interfering with my `Twig` Exception Controller?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer can be found here:

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/4-exception-controller-support.html

> FOSRestBundle defines two services for exception rendering, by default
>   it configures fos_rest.exception.controller which only supports
>   rendering via a serializer. In case no explicit controller is
>   configured by the user and TwigBundle is detected it will
>   automatically configure fos_rest.exception.twig_controller which
>   additionally also supports rendering via Twig.

So you need to extend:
FOS\RestBundle\Controller\TwigExceptionController